# Can a formula for this function be discerned?

Tags: functions

I have access to a function, but I do not know the underlying algorithm.  I'm attempting to guess it.  I can feed it inputs and examine the outputs.

I'll define it as $v(t,(x,y))$ where $t \in \mathbb N$ and $x,y \in \mathbb R$.  $(x,y)$ denotes that $v$ takes a cartesian coordinate as its second parameter.  Though, we could probably just as easily think of it as $v(t,x,y)$.

I was able to get some sample outputs by querying various inputs:

```
v(1,(0,0)) = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
v(2,(0,0)) = (2.0, 0.0, 0.0)
v(3,(0,0)) = (3.0, 0.0, 0.0)
v(3,(1,0)) = (2.99954308546917, 0.0523572193118505, 0.0)
v(1,(1,0)) = (0.999847695156391, 0.0174524064372835, 0.0)
v(2,(1,0)) = (1.99969539031278, 0.034904812874567, 0.0)
v(3,(1,0)) = (2.99954308546917, 0.0523572193118505, 0.0)
v(4,(1,0)) = (3.99939078062557, 0.0698096257491341, 0.0)
v(1,(1,1)) = (0.999695413509548, 0.0174497483512505, 0.0174524064372835)
v(2,(1,1)) = (1.9993908270191, 0.034899496702501, 0.034904812874567)
v(3,(1,1)) = (2.99908624052864, 0.0523492450537515, 0.0523572193118505)
v(4,(1,1)) = (3.99878165403819, 0.069798993405002, 0.0698096257491341)
```

From what I can gather, $v(t,x,y) = (t*a,t*b,t*c)$ where $a$,$b$, and $c$ somehow depend on $x$ and $y$.  Also, I'm thinking that the output is some sort of 3d vector.  Anyways, I've stared that the outputs for a while and I cannot readily discover a pattern, do you see it?  If not, is there any other input/output pairs I can provide to help or some methodology you would recommend?

Comment: If you want to treat the function as black-box you can easily use design of experiments methodology. Check this link http://www.sigmaflowdownloads.com/GettingStarted/Coach/DMAIC2/References/Full_Factorial.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some interesting elements (exact up to precision provided) :
\begin{align}
v(1,(1,0)) &= (0.999847695156391, 0.0174524064372835, 0.0)\\
&=\left(\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{180}\right),\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{180}\right),0\right)\\
&=\left(\cos(1°),\sin(1°),0\right)\\
v(2,(1,0)) &=2\,v(1,(1,0))\\
v(3,(1,0)) &=3\,v(1,(1,0))\\
v(1,(1,1)) &= (0.999695413509548, 0.0174497483512505, 0.0174524064372835)\\
&=\left(\cos(1°)\cos(1°),\ \sin(1°)\cos(1°),\ \sin(1°)\right)
\end{align}
So that the first element seems to be a radius and the couple at the end two angles in degrees.
The result should just be the usual projection : 
$$\boxed{v(r,(\theta,\phi))=(r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi),\ r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\ r\sin(\phi))}$$
or something of this kind...

Comment: Awesome work and insight, this must be it.

Comment: Thanks @user17753 ! It helped to have the right bias and to compute $0.999847695156391^2+0.0174524064372835^2$ (getting the wrong answer first didn't matter...).

Comment: Hey just a quick follow-up, having trouble finding this `projection` equation explained on the web.  Does it have a name, or some other kind of history to look it up?

Comment: @user17753: See ['spherical coordinates'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates). $\theta$ is the rotation in the horizontal plane (see the second figure from the top of the link) and $\phi$ is the complementary to $90°$ (i.e. $90-\phi\ $ that is the angle from the hashed horizontal line to Or) of the angle from Oz at the top to Or.

Comment: @user17753: maybe this might be more familiar to you: think of a globe, and think of $\theta$ as "longitude" and $\phi$ as the complementary angle of the "latitude".

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is that each of the three components of the output is a linear combination of the functions $t$, $tx$, and $ty$. You should compute a (least-squares) regression to find the coefficients $q,r,s$ that make $qt+rtx+sty$ best fit the data. There will be three such triples $q,r,s$, one for each output component. For example, in the last component, it looks like $q=r=0$ and $s\approx0.01745$.